# AS3 Property not found

Tags: actionscript-3

I have made this new function in my main class file:

```
check2(1);
function check2(somenumber:Number){
var Somenumber:Number = somenumber;

trace(Points.tab1_points); // traces actual variable for example "10"

var test:String = "Points.tab" + Somenumber+ "_points";
trace("test"); // traces "Points.tab1_points"

trace(this["Points.tab" + Somenumber+ "_points"]); //gives error
}
```

'

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property Points.tab1_points not found on Main and there is no default value.

    at Main/check2()[...\Main.as:641]
    at Main/Check()[...\Main.as:388]

Test Movie terminated.
```

I need to trace the value but through dynamic string.
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access to property of property. So you need do next:

```
var points:Object = this["Points"];
var tabPoints:Object = points["tab" + Somenumber+ "_points"];
trace(tabPoints);
```

Instead of type "Object" you can use appropriate types.

UPDATED:

If `Points` is a class name, then you can just write next:

```
trace(Points["tab" + Somenumber+ "_points"]);
```

Comment: Its not working..I forgot to mention,Points is a class name since variable tab1_points is static var in Points class file.

Comment: Im getting this error:Property Ability not found on Main and there is no default value.

Comment: Your comment changes all =). Class Points not a part of any another class. So, you can access to your property directly from any place. I will update answer.